# Rock, paper, scissors game in expressjs typescript

Tags: javascript, object-oriented, typescript, express.js, rock-paper-scissors

This is a simple 2 player game made in NodeJS and the ExpressJS framework with typescript. I've built using OOP approach to as far of an extent as I know of it. I'm really curious as to how further more I could improve it to satisfy even more of OOP principles and enhance extensibility.

```
import { IRuleSet, ruleSet } from './../shared/constants/ruleSet';
import { Player } from './player.model';

export type IGameResult = {
  player1Score?: number;
  player2Score?: number;
  message: string;
};

export class Game {
  ruleSet: IRuleSet;
  player1: Player;
  player2: Player;
  constructor(player1: Player, player2: Player) {
    this.player1 = player1;
    this.player2 = player2;
    this.ruleSet = ruleSet;
  }

    whoWins(player1Move: string, player2Move: string) {
      let result: IGameResult = {
        player1Score: undefined,
        player2Score: undefined,
        message: 'Invalid Choice',
      };
    if (ruleSet[player1Move.toLocaleLowerCase()].includes(player2Move)) {
      result = {
        player1Score: this.player1.incrementPoint(),
        player2Score: this.player2.getScore(),
        message: `Player 1 Wins with ${player1Move}`,
      };
      return result;
    } else if (ruleSet[player2Move.toLocaleLowerCase()].includes(player1Move)) {
      result = {
        player1Score: this.player1.getScore(),
        player2Score: this.player2.incrementPoint(),
        message: `Player 2 Wins with ${player2Move}`,
      };
      return result;
    } else {
      result = {
        player1Score: this.player1.getScore(),
        player2Score: this.player2.getScore(),
        message: 'Draw',
      };
      // Return a default value if no match is found

      return result;
    }
  }
}
```

```
// rules
export interface IRuleSet{
  [key: string]: string[];
}

export const ruleSet: IRuleSet = {
  rock: ['scissors'],
  scissors: ['paper'],
  paper: ['rock'],
};
```

```
// app.ts
import express, { Express } from 'express';
import morgan from 'morgan';
import setRoutes from './routes';
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
const app: Express = express();

class Server {
  constructor(app: Express) {
    this.init();
    this.useMiddleware(app);
    this.setRoutes(app);
    this.listen(app);
  }

  init() {
    dotenv.config();
    app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
    app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');

    console.log('Starting Express Server...');
  }
  useMiddleware(app: Express) {
    app.use(express.json());
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
    app.use(morgan('dev'));
    app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public/styles'));
  }
  setRoutes(app: Express) {
    console.log('Setting up routes...');
    setRoutes(app);
  }
  listen(app: Express) {
    app.listen(process.env.PORT, () => {
      console.log(`Server listening on port ${process.env.PORT}`);
    });
  }
}

new Server(app);
```

```
// game.controller.ts

export class GameController {
  public async home(_: Request, res: Response) {
    res.render('home');
  }

  public play(req: Request, res: Response) {
    const { player1Move, player2Move, player1, player2 } = req.body;

    const game = new Game(player1, player2);

    const { player1Score, player2Score, message } = game.whoWins(
      player1Move,
      player2Move
    );

    res.render('game', {
      message,
      player1Score: player1Score || game.player1.getScore(),
      player2Score: player2Score || game.player2.getScore(),
    });
  }

  public newPlay(req: Request, res: Response) {
    const { player1, player2 } = req.body;
    const game = new Game(player1, player2);

    res.render('game', {
      message: '',
      player1Score: game.player1.resetScore(),
      player2Score: game.player2.resetScore(),
    });
  }
}
```

```
// middleware 

import { Player } from '../models/player.model';
import { Request, Response, NextFunction } from 'express';
import { table } from 'console';

export const initPlayers = (req: Request, _: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
  req.body = {
    ...req.body,
    player1: Player.getFirstInstance(),
    player2: Player.getSecondInstance(),
  };
  next();
};
```

```
// Player

export class Player {
  private score: number;
  private static instance1: Player | undefined;
  private static instance2: Player | undefined;
  constructor(score: number = 0) {
    this.score = score;
  }

  incrementPoint() {
    return this.setScore(this.getScore() + 1);
  }

  getScore() {
    return Number(this.score);
  }

  setScore(score: number = 0) {
    this.score = score;

    return this.score;
  }

  resetScore() {
    return this.setScore();
  }

  static getFirstInstance() {
    return (Player.instance1 = Player.instance1 || new Player());
  }

  static getSecondInstance() {
    return (Player.instance2 = Player.instance2 || new Player());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Object-Oriented Programming is based on four pillars:

- Abstraction
- Encapsulation
- Inheritance
- Polymorphism

We can improve easily two pillars: abstraction and encapsulation.

## Encapsulation

> ```
> res.render('game', {
>    // ...,
>    player1Score: game.player1.resetScore(),
>    // ...
> });
> ```

The statement `game.player1.resetScore()` is called a *train wrack*. But it does not only look odd, there is even a “law” why it should be avoided: [Law of Demeter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter).

The statement `game.player1.resetScore()` ignores encapsulation. The object `game` exposes its internal `player1`.

Instead of asking for the player to reset the score, we should tell the game to reset the score. This is also known as *[Tell don't ask](https://www.martinfowler.com/bliki/TellDontAsk.html)*: `game.resetScore()`.

To support encapsulation it is common to make the internals of an object private:

```
class Game {
    constructor(private player1: Player, private player2: Player) {
    }

    // ...
}
```

## Abstraction

> ```
> if (ruleSet[player1Move.toLocaleLowerCase()].includes(player2Move)) {
> // ...    
> }
> ```

We can abstract `ruleSet[player1Move.toLocaleLowerCase()].includes(player2Move)`. To understand what this statemend is doing, we need to activate our brain cells a little.

A good abstraction helps our brain to understand code much quicker. A abstraced version could look like this:

```
if (moveOfPlayerOne.isBeating(moveOfPlayerTwo)) {
    // ...
}
```

## Naming

> ```
> whoWins(player1Move: string, player2Move: string) {
>    let result: IGameResult = {
>          player1Score: undefined,
>          player2Score: undefined,
>          message: 'Invalid Choice',
>    }
>
>    // ...
>
>    return result
> }
> ```

When I read `whoWins` at the first time, I thougt it would return a `Player`. This `whoWins` sounds like *who will win? Player1 or Player2?*

## A possible Implementation based on yours

```
class Game {
    constructor(private player1: Player, private player2: Player) {
    }

    play(moveOfPlayerOne: Move, moveOfPlayerTwo: Move): Result {
        if (moveOfPlayerOne.isBeating(moveOfPlayerTwo)) {
            this.player1.incrementScore()

            return {
                playerOne: this.player1,
                playerTwo: this.player2,
                message: `Player 1 wins with ${moveOfPlayerOne.asString()}`
            }
        }

        if (moveOfPlayerTwo.isBeating(moveOfPlayerOne)) {
            this.player2.incrementScore()

            return {
                playerOne: this.player1,
                playerTwo: this.player2,
                message: `Player 2 wins with ${moveOfPlayerTwo.asString()}`
            }
        }

        return {
            playerOne: this.player1,
            playerTwo: this.player2,
            message: 'Draw'
        }
    }

    // ...
}
```

I hope this will help you as a little inspiration. From here you can easily improve more. :)